# Javascript Window vs window

Tags: javascript

In Javascript I am adding a global variable to the `window` object. But it looks like I am able to do either of these two versions of `Window`/`window`:

```
Window.foo = "Bar";
window.foo = "Bar";
```

**What is the difference between the`Window` and `window`?** Is one just an alias for another? Which one is standard? I cannot find any documentation explaining a difference between the two. Is this a non-standard feature to accommodate bad syntax?