# What is the difference between Window and window?

Tags: javascript, dom

What is `Window` ?

Here's what I see on the console in Chrome :

```
    window
    Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, 
chrome: Object…}

    Window
    function Window() { [native code] }
```

Comment: `Window.foo = "Bar"; typeof foo;` `->` `"undefined"`. So no, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Felix Kling I had been accessing the variables via `Window.foo`, so I never noticed the problem of directly referencing at as `foo`.

Comment: Well, that just shows that setting a property on `Window` works, which is not really surprising (since it is an object).

Comment: Agreed, seems like I should have noticed what was going on sooner.

Comment: In the future, questions like this can be improved by doing some research such as looking up [`Window` in the Mozilla Developer Network reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window) is a function, as you can see. It's the constructor for the windows (but you can't build new windows directly with the constructor, you usually use the [`Window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open) function). `Window.prototype` thus holds the methods you can call on the window).

`window` is the global variable holding an instance of `Window`, it represents the browser window containing your document (not really a "window" usually, rather a tab in modern browsers).

You can check that

```
window instanceof Window
```

is

```
true
```

Comment: constructor ? Why new Window() return Error?

Comment: @zloctb Because scripts can't build new windows this way, they must use the Window.open function.

Comment: @zloctb: You can do `var x = Object.create(Window.prototype)` and x is now an instance of `Window`, however, `x` is not identical to the already existing `window` instance as it is not "bound" to the current window in your browser. Hence `window` has several more local properties. For example `x.Location` won't exist among other things.

Comment: It's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/23547708/218196, but your answer is actually better. Should we close the other one as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: @FelixKling It seems ok. But I won't do it myself for obvious reasons.

Comment: On the other side, the other question is better phrased. I will flag for merge.

Answer (score 12):

`Window` is the constructor function that is used to create `window`.

To see this, try `alert(window.constructor === Window)`.

Comment: That makes total sense. So when I add a variable to `Window`, it is really storing it in the `Window` object, not actually making a global variable as it would with `window.foo`.

Comment: Correct.  Javascript is case-sensitive; the fact that they differ only in case is irrelevant.

Comment: For further confusion, try `Window.prototype`.

Comment: why people say alert, why not console.log?

Answer (score 2):

console outputs from the Chrome browser:

```
console.log(window instanceof Window);      // true
console.log(window.constructor === Window); // true
console.log(this);   // Window {document:document, alert:ƒ, setTimeout:ƒ,..}
console.log(window); // Window {document:document, alert:ƒ, setTimeout:ƒ,..}
console.log(Window); // ƒ Window() { [native code] }
```