# JavaScript Global Object Window and window

Tags: javascript

I want to ask what is different between `Window` and `window` global object in the JavaScript? 
I used them and got different results.

Example (using `window`)

```
(function (GlobalObj, name) {
  var greeting = 'Hello';
  GlobalObj.greeting = 'Replace Hola'
  console.log(greeting + ',' + name);
}(window, 'Melo'));

console.log(greeting);
```

Result: 
Hello,Melo
Replace Hola

Example (using `Window`)

```
(function (GlobalObj, name) {
  var greeting = 'Hello';
  GlobalObj.greeting = 'Replace Hola'
  console.log(greeting + ',' + name);
}(Window, 'Melo'));

console.log(greeting);
```

Result: 
Hello,Melo
Hola

Comment: One is an object, the other a function.

Comment: also shouldn't we get the same result in both the cases.

Comment: @zer00ne That’s completely wrong. None of those is a keyword, `Window` is not the `window` object and `window` is not an undeclared variable.

Comment: `typeof Window` => function, `typeof window` => object

Comment: @Xufox thanks. Your post is what I want to ask.

Comment: @Xufox : The same thing should be logged in the console, because Window and window are different but the property greeting has the same value. I they are being used in similar way, I just tried it now and got the same text logged.

Comment: Go to the console and type `Window` and then `window` and observe the different.

Comment: @nnnnnn It's sorta kinda a duplicate, but there's more confusion here than just that between `window` and `Window` that could bear explaining.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example first declares and initializes a **local** variable named `greeting`, which will be accessible only from within the function, and will shadow any global `greeting` property on `window`. Then in the next line, it sets a `greeting` property on the `window` object, which by the nature of properties on the `window` object, is a **global** variable which can be accessed using just `greeting` (if not shadowed by a local variable, as it is in this case).

You are getting confused by the fact that when `greeting` is used in the `console.log`, outside the function, at the end of the second example, it is picking up the value from `window` set in the first example. You need to test the second example in isolation. To do so, before running it type `delete window.greeting;` or refresh the browser, to remove the `greeting` property on `window` which was set in the first example. However, in strict mode this will result in a `ReferenceError` due to `greeting` not being defined. In the second snippet below, to get around this, I've defined `greeting` in the global scope.

Assigning a property to `Window` as in the second example accomplishes nothing. Nothing on `Window` (which is the window constructor) is ever used for anything. You might as well assign the `greeting` property to an empty object, or not assign it at all.

```js
(function (GlobalObj, name) {
  var greeting = 'Hello';
  GlobalObj.greeting = 'Replace Hola';   // assigns to `window.greeting` === `greeting`
  console.log(greeting + ', ' + name);    // prints local `greeting`
}(window, 'Melo'));

console.log(greeting);                   // prints `window.greeting`
```

```js
var greeting;

(function (GlobalObj, name) {
  var greeting = 'Hello';
  GlobalObj.greeting = 'Replace Hola';   // assigns to `Window.greeting`
  console.log(greeting + ', ' + name);    // prints local `greeting`
}(Window, 'Melo'));

console.log(greeting);                   // prints `window.greeting` (undefined)
```

Here are some tips:

1. Don't use `Window` if you're trying to access global variables. Use `window`. `Window` is meaningless and irrelevant.
2. Don't use global variables at all.
3. If you do use global variables, avoid confusing yourself and others by defining local variables with the same name inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

The window object represents an open window in a browser.

If a document contain frames ( tags), the browser creates one window object for the HTML document, and one additional window object for each frame.

Note: There is no public standard that applies to the Window object, but all major browsers support it.

However, Window is a function. It's the constructor for the windows (but you can't build new windows directly with the constructor, you usually use the Window.open function). Window.prototype thus holds the methods you can call on the window).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008630/what-is-the-difference-between-window-and-window) for more info.

Comment: _“There is no public standard that applies to the Window object”_ — what exactly do you mean there? There’s [this thing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#the-window-object).

Comment: @Xufox - *That* old thing?

Comment: @nnnnnn _“Last Updated 9 December 2016”_. I mean it’s a standard and it’s public. You might as well say, it’s a public standard. And it exists.

Comment: @Xufox - I was kidding around.