# What is window.Window?

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble tracking this down for somewhat obvious reasons. What is the `Window` object in javascript? *Not* the `window` object..

Using `console.dir(Window)` in Chrome shows it has the properties `PERSISTANT`, `TEMPORARY` and a `length`.

Comment: [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window) vs [`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window). It's the same as [the difference between Document and document in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16790174/1048572)

Comment: `Window == window.constructor`

Comment: Thanks guys, that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Bergi Mind adding http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008630/what-is-the-difference-between-window-and-window as one of the dupes? Thanks

Comment: @AndrewLi Thanks, that's a much better duplicate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the interface that the global `window` object is an instance of. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) says:

> The `window` object implements the `Window` interface, which in turn inherits from the `AbstractView` interface.

A W3C spec defines the interface here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#window

Answer (score 1):

Window is the constructor function that is used to create window.
Try `alert(window.constructor);`