# Window.location is not working on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to redirect to another view using javascript on button click. The reason I need to use the javascript is because I need the "`Account Id`" of the row I am clicking. Below is the my code

**This is to render the page**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 

href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link href="@Url.Content("~/css/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#acctInfo").DataTable();
        //$(".td_0").hide();
    });
</script>

<!-- Page Title
   ============================================= -->
<section id="page-title">

    <div class="container clearfix">
        <h1>View Accounts</h1>
    </div>
</section><!-- #page-title end -->


<section id="content">
    <div class="content-wrap">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover" id="acctInfo">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="td_0">Account Id</th>
                    <th>Employee Id</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Business Name</th>
                    <th>Account Type</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach (var i in Model.AccountsViews)
                {
                    <tr id="rowx">
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.AcctId)</td>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.EmployeeId)</td>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.FirstName)</td>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.MiddleName)</td>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.LastName)</td>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.BusinessName)</td>
                        <td> @Html.DisplayFor(m => i.AccountType)</td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="lnkDetail btn btn-success form-control">Detail</a></td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="lnkEdit btn btn-success form-control">Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="lnkDelete btn btn-danger form-control">Delete</a></td>

                        @*<td>
                                <input type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-success form-control" onclick="EditSelected(this)">
                                <input id="btn_edit[]" type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-success form-control" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-success form-control" />
                            </td>*@
                    </tr>
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div id="divEdit" style="display: none;">

    <input type="hidden" id="hidId"/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Employee Id</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtEmployeeId" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtFirstName" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Middle Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtMiddleName" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtLastName" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Business Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtBusinessName" class="form-control"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Account Type</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList("ddlAccount", new List<SelectListItem>
                {
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Supplier", Value = "Supplier"},
                    new SelectListItem{Text = "Employee", Value = "Employee"}
                }, new{@class="form-control", id="ddlAccount"})
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**This is the javascript to navigate me to another view**

```
 $('a.lnkDetail').on("click", function () {

        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var acctId = row.find("td:eq(0)").html().trim();
        var url = '@Url.Action("ViewAccountDetail", "AccountWVehicle")?acctId=' + acctId;

        Window.location = url;


        return false;
    });
```

When I use the `alert(url)`, "I get the correct url like so `"/ViewAccountDetail/AccountVehicle?acctId=7"`

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You never actually set `window.location` to your new url.

Comment: You don't do anything with your URL. What makes you think `window.location` is not working if you're not trying to set it?

Comment: What do you mean Darth? As soon as I invoke the action "ViewAccountDetail", I am supposed to be navigated to its' view.

Comment: Now you've edited the question to try to set the location, but you're using `Window`, that won't work. The correct name is `window` (lowercase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `location.href` to your new url, for example:

```
location.href = '/'
```

Comment: This did the trick! Window.location = url  // does not work Window.location.href // does not work either but location.href does! Thank you! I'd click on the check as soon as I am able to. I need to wait for 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href = url;` will work

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $('a.lnkDetail').on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var acctId = row.find("td:eq(0)").html().trim();
    window.location = '@Url.Action("ViewAccountDetail", "AccountWVehicle")?acctId=' + acctId;
});
```

More info here: [What is the difference between Window and window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008630/what-is-the-difference-between-window-and-window)